# El vídeo no se puede reproducir (Videoview con streaming)

Tags: java, android, webview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de streaming de vídeo con un servidor alojado en **000webhost**, todo funciona bien, pero al momento de reproducir el vídeo solo carga una porción de este (1 a 2 minutos aproximadamente), y al llegar al límite de la fracción del vídeo que se cargo aparece un dialogo que dice ***"El vídeo no se puede reproducir"*** 3 veces. Preguntas:

1- ¿ Por qué no carga todo el vídeo ?

2- ¿ Por qué sale este mensaje 2 o 3 veces ?

3- ¿ Por qué al resumir el vídeo lo retrasa unos segundos (10 aprox.) e inicia desde ese punto ?

4- ¿ Cómo puedo solucionar esto ?

Código:

```
public class T1xC01 extends AppCompatActivity{

    public VideoView t1c1;
    private int posicion = 0;
    private MediaController media;
    public TextView cap_r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_t1x_c01);

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        cap_r = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cap_r);
        t1c1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.t1c1);

        Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String datos = parametros.getString("video");
        cap_r.setText(datos);

        String vid = cap_r.getText().toString();

        if(datos != null){

            if(vid.equals("1")){
                t1c1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                Uri c = Uri.parse("https://xxxxx.000webhostapp.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.mp4");
                t1c1.setVideoURI(c);
                t1c1.requestFocus();
                t1c1.start();
            }else if(vid.equals("2")){
                t1c1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                Uri c = Uri.parse("https://xxxxx.000webhostapp.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.mp4");
                t1c1.setVideoURI(c);
                t1c1.requestFocus();
                t1c1.start();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se recivieron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        posicion = t1c1.getCurrentPosition();
        t1c1.pause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        t1c1.seekTo(posicion);
        t1c1.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { regresar(); }

    public void regresar(){
        onPause();
        AlertDialog.Builder salir = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        salir.setTitle("Salir del vídeo");
        salir.setMessage("¿Estás seguro de que deseas salir de este vídeo?");
        salir.setPositiveButton("Sí, quiero salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        salir.setNegativeButton("No, quiero seguir viendo el capítulo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                onResume();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = salir.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: La app, no se te cierra ni te arroja errores ? si es así, puede que tus server tenga un limite de subida/bajada de datos.(cuentas free)

Comment: No, no sé cierra ni marca errores, puede que sea eso, ¡muchas gracias por tu respuesta!